# Calling getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) when using a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an Activity that hosts a ViewPager with 2 fragments. I want to remove the content in the Action Bar so that the tabs for the ViewPager will be up in the Action Bar, so I use this:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The problem is, when I try to add a navigation drawer onto this activity, I get this error:

```
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.TestMap}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:279)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3264)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:62)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at com.example.test.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:38)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at com.example.test.TestMap.onCreate(TestMap.java:29)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-25 15:37:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(18059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
```

And here is my activity:

```
public class TestMap extends BaseActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
String TabFragmentB;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "List View", "Map View" };

private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_map);

    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

public void setTabFragmentB(String t) {
    TabFragmentB = t;
}

public String getTabFragmentB() {
    return TabFragmentB;
}

}
```

So, basically, if I remove `extends BaseActivity` and all of the code involving this class, it works, and the navigation drawer opens (it just isn't customized to what I need). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call getActionBar() after setContentView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_map);

    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//code ...
```